# Android - Other App launches my App after Web Link was clicked in that other App

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-launcher

I do not know if you get my question right, so let me explain:

My app is shown in the chooser after user clicks a web link in any other app, then user clicks on my app and my app shows the link in a `webview`. This works fine.

But, the problem is when the user launches the other app again (which invoked my app earlier) with a click on the icon that is on the home screen or app drawer, it opens my app again instead of the origin app.

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.droidfox.app.browser"
    android:label="@string/browser"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Back Button Override:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () 
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why the other app launches my app and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you implementing a web browser? Otherwise; use something else than http and https as schemes. Or at least specify host so that you do not launch on all types of http requests.

Comment: Try to put `android:noHistory` in your activity manifest.

Comment: @gunar: Jup, that was it! Thank you and all the others who tried to help me. Please feel free to add this as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @DroidFox: sure, you're welcome, glad I could help you. Don't forget to upvote if an answer was really helpful

Comment: @gunar: Already did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `android:noHistory` for your given activity. 
Taken from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist):

`Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".
A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.`